# GNUplot throws error on date plotting

Tags: linux, gnuplot

Today I wanted to make an automated way to calculate actions in a certain timeframe however GNUplot throws out this error:

```
"today.p", line 10: x range is invalid
```

today.p has the following options:

```
set datafile separator ","
set autoscale fix
set style data lines
set key outside right center
set timefmt '"%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'
set format x '%H'
set title "Product Key Generation "
set output 'test.png'
set term png
plot 'result.csv' u 1:($1) title "Product Keys" with lines
```

the result.csv looks like this:

```
productkey,activatedat
ACHIZ-wYMIV-UQaHO-mwabr,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
NWUBO-cLcTr-L4Ia6-llvyw,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
VXWGQ-UKHao-kq2j1-avuka,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
NVVFK-3mz8v-27avd-lztgm,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
PGSRV-oQ2G3-afGRg-kxzob,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
BULEL-CU1bE-GWxRf-hucwa,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
ANKWL-LBW8B-il3tM-zzklf,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
ZSDVL-tZcdY-YRJJQ-ddctr,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
ZSQLX-pmAp2-Dp3h9-ejtfu,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
IWKUL-hFhDs-GPapK-fwgmr,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
GSYAU-eIUjm-2h4O1-gfmmf,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
OQTDJ-rXkyz-bt18d-skfvp,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
EKTMD-uOUbA-XEWtP-gyfac,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
DCPWO-H98qT-FSdZU-qbbqh,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
ZXSMC-AsiRf-6zkwv-aidor,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
OGJLE-NyTxe-HuJK5-dwtty,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
FZETE-BTTA4-W0I0p-bmxah,"2018-08-22 00:00:01"
```

I just cant figure out whats wrong here. Google has nothing for this result and I am pretty new to GNUplot

Comment: Your plot command says to take x from column 1 (which contains a non-numeric string hash). Evidently you really want to take x from column 2 (which is a date). But they are all the same date so that won't work either. What exactly do you want the plot to look like? What is x? What is y? where do you want it to print the key string?

Comment: The plot should look like this https://i.imgur.com/DUk0Iwe.png (made in excel) however i need an automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix the time format (extra quotes, wrong year format), and then

```
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
plot 'result.csv' using 2:(1.0) smooth frequency with lines
```

This adds a count of (1.0) for every entry with identical x coordinate (time) in column 2.

Comment: This works flawless however my approach with the timefmt was right (the ones with the quotes, the year was wrong), it wont work with your timefmt (https://i.imgur.com/IRxaf9D.png). How would I go about adding labels to the peaks? I have tried `plot 'ProductKey.csv' using 2:(1.0) smooth frequency with lines lw 2, 'ProductKey.csv' using 2:1:(sprintf("(%d, %d)", $1, $2)) with labels notitle` however that didnt work out as it displays nothing

Comment: I do not of a good way to add labels of the sort you show in the sample plot.